# How to combine raster files (.img) into a mosaic and then clip around a boundary?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, dem

I'm new to QGIS and the tutorials I've tried don't seem to be working. Using QGIS 3.10

I downloaded a LiDAR DTM package from Ontario GeoHub. I found about 60 files that cover my boundary outline shapefile.

1. I'd like to stitch the raster images together (not overlay) (since I believe you need one raster layer for the next step to clip?)
2. I'd like to clip the raster image to the shapefile outline of a selected area. Aka I want just the raster image to be inside of the boundary-outline shapefile.

I either get a large black square after I try to clip or nothing seems to happen... I've tried to stitch the images together using merge and build virtual raster. In terms of clipping I've tried "clip raster by mask extent", and the clip functions.

https://geohub.lio.gov.on.ca/datasets/776819a7a0de42f3b75e40527cc36a0a?geometry=-82.063%2C43.286%2C-78.117%2C43.982

Comment: Which files is it in the link?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @BERA I'm using "Lidar DTM Brampton 2015 Package A" Brampton's data from the link.